# Retrieve custom fields from standard objects using sfdx force:source:retrieve

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

How can I retrieve custom fields from standard objects using:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m
```

I tried using `CustomField` to no avail.

I am trying to pull the custom fields I have added from a non-tracked org (i.e. a non-scratch org) that only supports MDAPI directly into the newer SFDX format.

Comment: This seems like a pretty clearly asked question. Why is this closed as "unclear"?

Comment: I've noticed this trend quite some time ago. Mods that never had any serious exposure to certain aspects of Salesforce have no idea about the question. Particularly bad when asking developer questions and clueless admins kill questions down. Also super annoying when people ask for code samples when question was clearly a conceptual one.

Comment: Yeah this was closed by the community, not a moderator. Going to re-open it because was about to ask this exact question myself, it has all the information it needs.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This syntax was what I needed

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomField:Claim.CveClaim__c
```

to retrieve my custom field `CveClaim__c` that I added to the (standard in FSC object) Claim. The `-m CustomObject:Account` will pull back all the fields of that object - standard and custom.

Comment: I know this wasn't the original question, but I can't get this to work with custom fields on *custom* objects. I just get "No results found". Has anyone found a way to retrieve source for custom fields on custom objects without having to retrieve the entire custom object including *all* its fields?

Comment: Hi @Frans, I would expect it to work: have you got the right namespace prefix on the object name and field name?

Comment: I would expect many things to work on Salesforce, and particularly on DX, that just don’t. This is apparently one of them.

Comment: For anyone that still trying to get custom fields on custom objects. I was able to get a custom field from a custom object in a managed package using the command: `sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomField:packagenamespace__CustomObject__c.MyField__c`

Comment: This definitely works with custom objects.  My example: `sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomField:Employee_Profile__c.Last_Submitted_Timesheet__c`

Comment: The `sf` version is: `sf project retrieve start --metadata CustomField:Claim.CveClaim__c`

Answer (score 4):

You have to specifically name the objects you want, e.g. `-m CustomObject:Account,Opportunity`

Alternatives I know of:

1) Use this VSCode plugin to easily produce a package.xml by point and click, then retrieve against that.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VignaeshRamA.sfdx-package-xml-generator

2) Use shane-sfdx-plugins which supports a syntax `sfdx shane:mdapi:pull --type=CustomObject` but will actually pull standard objects too.

https://github.com/mshanemc/shane-sfdx-plugins

Comment: As I can't post this more clearly because the question is closed, let me add that this syntax was what I needed `sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomField:Claim.CveClaim__c` to retrieve my custom field `CveClaim__c` that I added to the (standard in FSC object) Claim. The `-m CustomObject:Account` will pull back all the fields of that object - standard and custom.

Comment: That's fine if you want all the fields of the object, but sometimes it's more desirable to pull just the specific field from the object. In which case Keith C has provided a nice example of what command to use.

Comment: @KeithC Can you post this as an asnwer now? I just re-opened the question and your comment here is the exact answer I was after. Also, ping me when you do so I can up-vote :)

Comment: @MattLacey Done.